# Redirecting in a direct way, is it a good practice? Express, Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

I have two questions about express. From a user login page, I call the below API function.

1. Is there a reason for me to have `res.send(token)` in the below code, I have commented it out. Is this needed for testing Postman?
2. When this is being called, then is it a good practice to redirect to the site I want after it like `return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8081/en/UserSite/profile.html');`? Or do I need to think about extra settings, but for now, I can leave this as it is...

   ```
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
      //validates the request.
      const { error } = validate(req.body); 
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (!user)  return res.status(400).send('Invalid Email or Password.');

    //Here we compare the password for re-hashing the password.
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Email or Password.');

    //const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    //res.send(token);
    return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8081/en/UserSite/profile.html');

    });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send ONE response per http request so you would have either `res.send(token)` or `res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8081/en/UserSite/profile.html');`, but not both since they are each sending a separate http response.

Which one you want depends entirely upon what you want the result of this http request to be.  That isn't something we can determine for you.

> Is there a reason for me to have res.send(token) in the below code?

Yes, if you want the http request to return the token so it can be used by the caller.

> I have commented it out. Is this needed for testing Postman?

Again, this depends only upon what you want the result for your http request to be.  This should have nothing to do with Postman.  It has to do with the design objective for your http request and what result you want the client to receive.

> When this is being called, then is it a good practice to redirect to the site I want after it like return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8081/en/UserSite/profile.html');? Or do I need to think about extra settings, but for now, I can leave this as it is...

Again, this depends upon what the design objective is for this route is which you have not shared.  The code looks like it is generating a token that you don't seem to do anything else with so if you don't return the token to the client, I don't know what the point of the entire route would be.

Typically a JWT token like this would be used for programmatic access to a REST API.  For general browser access, you would store some sort of sessionID in a cookie and then you may redirect after login and the cookie can remain in effect to indicate this is a logged in client.  To be useful by itself a JWT token has to be returned to the client and then the client has to present that token on future http requests.  This is something that a browser does not do by itself for general web page browsing so this would be used for programmatic access (such as Ajax calls).

Comment: So if I understand you, then typically I would use `res.send(token)` which would be used in cookies, which would help to store the session of the logged-in user? This is what I wanted to know. Thank you. I want only the user to be logged in and store the information about it's session so that it can be used in other html links. Not sure how I will achieve this, but this will lead me to the correct path. Thank you!

Comment: @RaitisLebedevs - Not really.  `res.send(token)` delivers a token to the client and the client can then present that token (usually in a custom header) on subsequent API calls.  Cookies for a browser login session are a different implementation and would not typically use a JWT token like this.  For a session implementation, see [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).